# Neatline disappears when resized

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, layouts

New-ish to GIS.

Using Arc 10.3 and experiencing an annoying problem. When attempting to resize a neatline (in order to use it as a locator box on my inset reference map) the lines disappears when reduced in size too quickly, or after getting below ~0.6x0.6". The blue vertices remain visible afterwards, but cannot be selected/moved/brought forward.

Any thoughts or work arounds?

Comment: you will need to explain a little more clearly.  are you using layouts? are you zooming to a scale inside the data frame?  It sounds like you should learn some more about layouts. Are you editing the neatline? we cant tell what it is you are attempting or referring to.

Comment: I am editing a neatline in layouts.

Comment: Not sure how to explain what's happening any better. 
I'm in layout view, my first dataframe is my main map display, my second dataframe is the inset reference map. I want a tiny red locator box around my location on the reference map, so I add a neatline. But when I try to resize to make it small enough, it disappears, leaving only the vertices which can no longer be selected or edited.

Comment: go to the properties of the first data frame and select the extent indicator. Choose the thickness and color

Comment: To make what you are trying to describe in words clearer I think you should [edit] your question to revise it with a more detailed description that includes a screenshot or two.  You can use the Picture button to do this.

Comment: Thanks Brad, that's a helpful trick and possible work-around.

Answer (score 1):

You could check to see if the neatline element is falling behind another element when you resize it.

Try right clicking on the neatline and selecting "bring to front", then shrinking as before.

Answer (score 1):

This won't solve your neat line disappearing issue, but it might provide a better solution to what you're trying to achieve:

Follow these steps to create a locator box:

- Right-click in the table of contents, the data frame in which you would like to display the extent of the inset map, and select "Properties".
- In the Data Frame Properties window, select the "Extent Indicators" tab.
- Select the data frame for the inset map in the left box and click the ">" button to move it to the right box.
- Click "Apply" and the extent of the inset will be shown on your main map.

You can also add a leader between the extent and the data frame by checking the box in the options section of the dialog, as well as change the properties of the extend indicator and leader lines.

As you change the extent/scale etc of your inset, the indicator on your main map will automagically be updated accordingly.

[image: example extent indicators for inset map]